# connecting two laravel website with one database

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have made a website for Employers in Laravel 5. Now I want to connect and sync it with a second website on different domain but same server. The 2nd website is for jobseekers which will listen to events for database change by 1st application. For example if a candidate is shortlisted by a employer that corresponding event should be captured and handled in jobseeker application.  Please suggest a way to do that, I am not much experienced in Laravel.

Comment: There is not big deal. Just set the connection authentication data in the new laravel app, and that is all.

Comment: but how do I get to know if something has changed in DB due to one website.

Comment: [Task scheduling](http://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling) is a good option.

Comment: Best way is to use redis with laravel' event system two dir one db and one redis sharing data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the first website make an API call to the second to let it know something has changed. Alternatively, you can have the first website use [Laravel's event system](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/events) in conjunction with the [Queue system](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues). Your second application can connect to the database of first application to retrieve and modify its queue.

The API solution provides a bit more flexibility, especially if they were to ever be on separate servers. I would choose whichever you are more comfortable with, it wouldn't take long to implement either if you change your mind later.